# Get users that are 'memberof' a group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I got a working solution, however I'm pretty sure there is a less resource-intensive method because the current solution involves doing a query to get the groups member and then a query to get each users information.

Here is the code I have :

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://server:port" );
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher( root );
searcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN=foo-group))";

var members = (IEnumerable)searcher.FindOne()
              .GetDirectoryEntry()
              .Invoke( "members" );

Dictionary<string , string> results = new Dictionary<string , string>();

foreach( object member in members ) {
   DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry( member );
   results.Add( de.Properties[ "SAMAccountname" ][ 0 ].ToString(), de.Properties[ "cn" ][ 0 ].ToString() );
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do a single query to get every user that are member of a group, filters the properties to load and then display them. So something like this

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://server:port" );
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher( root );
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "cn" );
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "SAMAccountname" );
searcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(memberof=foo-group))";

foreach( var user in searcher.FindAll() ) {
    //do whatever...
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME");
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
{
    var groupName = "YourGroup";
    var sp = new GroupPrincipal(context, groupName);
    searcher.QueryFilter = sp;
    var group = searcher.FindOne() as GroupPrincipal;

    if (group == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Group Name: {0}", groupName);

    foreach (var f in group.GetMembers())
    {
        var principal = f as UserPrincipal;

        if (principal == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal.Name))
            continue;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", principal.Name);
    }
}
```

I have some VB code that'll do it the old way also, but this is definitely simpler with AccountManagement.

---

Here's the VB code I was referring to (again it isn't pretty but it's functional):

```
Public Function GetUsersByGroup(de As DirectoryEntry, groupName As String) As IEnumerable(Of DirectoryEntry)
    Dim userList As New List(Of DirectoryEntry)
    Dim group As DirectoryEntry = GetGroup(de, groupName)

    If group Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    For Each user In GetUsers(de)
        If IsUserInGroup(user, group) Then
            userList.Add(user)
        End If
    Next

    Return userList
End Function

Public Function GetGroup(de As DirectoryEntry, groupName As String) As DirectoryEntry
    Dim deSearch As New DirectorySearcher(de)

    deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(SAMAccountName=" & groupName & "))"

    Dim result As SearchResult = deSearch.FindOne()

    If result Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return result.GetDirectoryEntry()
End Function

Public Function GetUsers(de As DirectoryEntry) As IEnumerable(Of DirectoryEntry)
    Dim deSearch As New DirectorySearcher(de)
    Dim userList As New List(Of DirectoryEntry)

    deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=person))"

    For Each user In deSearch.FindAll()
        userList.Add(user.GetDirectoryEntry())
    Next

    Return userList
End Function

Public Function IsUserInGroup(user As DirectoryEntry, group As DirectoryEntry) As Boolean
    Dim memberValues = user.Properties("memberOf")

    If memberValues Is Nothing OrElse memberValues.Count = 0 Then Return False

    For Each g In memberValues.Value
        If g = group.Properties("distinguishedName").Value.ToString() Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

And usage:

```
Dim entries = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://...")
Dim userList As IEnumerable(Of DirectoryEntry) = GetUsersByGroup(entries, "GroupName")
```

Comment: This is working well, thank you. However what is the difference between this and the other method. Is there a way I can specify the server its searching on. I wanna make sure there is no discrepancies with some other data i am displaying.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what it is doing under the covers but I've mixed them before without any issues or discrepancies.

Comment: Do you have an idea how its associating the domain with the appropriate LDAP server?

Comment: If it becomes a problem you can use some of the other constructor overloads to control it more directly (or even just pass the name of the domain controller instead of the domain name itself). If you're really interested in how it works, the logic is in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLSAPDirectoryInit`. You can find the source by decompiling `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll`.

Comment: thanks for the info. I was watching those objects and found out that it generates an LDAP url that maps to some DNS entry/alias mapping to the exact server and port. I changed the url I had to the one that was in the object and the other method still works. So thank you :)

Comment: do you know any way of specifying the ldap server instead? just to be safe.

Comment: You should be able to pass it in place of the domain name. At least that is what I get from the docs.

Comment: all the groups that dont have the same cn and samaccountname are not loading at all. out of curiosity, can you post your vb code?

Comment: Sure. It's not pretty so hopefully I don't incur any losses for posting it... give me a minute to round it up.

Comment: this looks pretty much like the first solution I had implemented except that you are doing an extra check to look if the user is really in that group.

Comment: So it doesn't work for you? (Didn't you say your code wasn't working?)

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry objEntry = new DirectoryEntry(Ldapserver, userid, password);
DirectorySearcher personSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(objEntry);
personSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", username);
SearchResult result = personSearcher.FindOne();

if(result != null)
{
    DirectoryEntry personEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    PropertyValueCollection groups = personEntry.Properties["memberOf"];
    foreach(string g in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(g); // will write group name
    }
}
```

I originally used a method very similar to what you have posted and it took about 12 minutes to run through my entire company's AD and get the results. After switching to this method, it takes about 2 minutes. You will need to use the ldapserver address where I wrote ldapserver and the userid and password as well and username is the SAMAccountName for the person you're looking up.

Answer (score 2):

If you check [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180906%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can do the following:

```
DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=foo-group,DC=Cmp,DC=COM");
foreach(object dn in group.Properties["member"] )
    //do whatever
```

Comment: that wont work for me because I dont have the full path, I only have the CN

Answer (score 0):

It's shorter using `GroupPrincipal` method [`FindByIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.findbyidentity?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_GroupPrincipal_FindByIdentity_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_IdentityType_System_String_) which gives also multiple ways to identify the group with [`IdentityType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype) :

```
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME")
        {
            var userPrincipals = GroupPrincipal
                .FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "GROUP_ACCOUNT")
                .GetMembers(true) // recursive
                .OfType<UserPrincipal>();
            ...
        }
```