# check if user is a member of a group

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, active-directory-group

I have a code to check if the user is a member of a group. 
I am using this at my login.

Please note I have a domain user and local user eg. `testdomain\administrator` and `administrator`.

This is the code I use:

```
using (DirectoryEntry groupEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./" + userGroupName + ",group"))
{
    foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)groupEntry.Invoke("Members"))
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(member))
        {
            string completeName = memberEntry.Name;
            DirectoryEntry domainValue = GUIUtility.FindDomain(memberEntry);
            if (domainValue != null)
            {
                completeName = domainValue.Name + "\\" + memberEntry.Name;
            }
            Global.logger.Info("completeName from " + userGroupName + " = " + completeName);
            if (userName.Equals(completeName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Global.logger.Debug("IsUserPartOfWindowsGroup returned True with username =" + userName + " , UserGroupName = " + userGroupName);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    Global.logger.Debug("IsUserPartOfWindowsGroup returned false for username =" + userName + " , UserGroupName = " + userGroupName);
    return false;
}
```

This code works, but

```
DirectoryEntry domainValue = GUIUtility.FindDomain(memberEntry);
```

is taking a lot of time in the profiler as I see it. Is there a better/ faster way to handle this?

```
public static DirectoryEntry FindDomain(DirectoryEntry memberEntry)
{
    if (memberEntry.Parent != null)
    {
        if (memberEntry.Parent.SchemaClassName.Equals("domain", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return memberEntry.Parent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

another way:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, Password);
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=" + userName + ")(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")))";
SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();

Global.logger.Info("result == " + result.Path);
foreach (string GroupPath in result.Properties["memberOf"])
{
    if (GroupPath.Contains(adminGroupName))
    {
        Global.logger.Info(compUsrNameForEncryption + "exists in " + adminGroupName);
    }
}
```

Comment: We could probably help better if we knew what `GUIUtility.FindDomain` was. Also the new(ish) [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) classes make this sort of thing much simpler.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9603777/635634), the code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9604203/635634) to that question would probably help you out as well.

Comment: hey babcock.. i have added the finddomain function. also what if the user is not part of a domain?

Comment: Are you sure `FindDomain` is what is eating up your cycles? It doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Not part of a domain, meaning they are just a local user?

Comment: I know i use the eqatec profiler.. which says its taking a lot of time comparing other functions.. not a part of domain == local user.. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Your profiler probably says it takes a lot of time because it is called so much.

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty close to what I use:

```
public bool IsUserInGroup(string userName, string groupName)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    {
        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context) { SamAccountName = userName }))
        {
            using (var user = searcher.FindOne() as UserPrincipal)
            {
                return user != null && user.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it for local users though. The logic works in my domain, I just changed `PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)` so it should look at local users now.

*Don't forget to add a reference and using statement for `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`*

Comment: hey, i get an error nullrefrenceexception at :
return user.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

Comment: I also removed all sanity checks so you'll get that if `userName` was not a valid user.

Comment: My original code was missing some `using`s so I added them in and put in the necessary sanity check.

Comment: I tried this but it says the user is not part of the group.. basically user value is coming as null... i am giving the username as domain\username..

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the domain\ part. The username should be sufficient (that is what I use anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but couldn't you just do:

```
if(Page.User.IsInRole("GROUP NAME"))
{
    // user is in group. do your thing
}
else
{
    // user isn't in group
}
```

Works for me when I'm doing Active Directory authentication on ASP.NET.

EDIT: Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx) describing using Page.User.IsInRole(). Windows authentication must be used though, if you don't use Windows authentication, it won't work properly.

EDIT2: Since there Windows Authentication isn't being used this is how I would do it:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP Address,user,password);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
searcher.Filter = string.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", user);
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
bool isInGroup = false;
if (result != null)
{
    DirectoryEntry person = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    PropertyValueCollection groups = person.Properties["memberOf"];
    foreach (string g in groups)
    {
        if(g.Equals(groupName))
        {
           isInGroup = true;
           break;
        }
    }
}
return isInGroup;
```

Comment: You may be right, but I'm not an ASP.NET developer. The OP did say that they are looking for a solution that works with local users/groups though so if your solution works for that then you're answer is probably best.

Comment: @M.Babcock as long as the OP is using Windows Authentication then this will work. If not, then your answer is the way to go

Comment: i dont use the windows authentication.. and this is defined in a class.. so page wont work.. thanks

Comment: @user175084 I have edited my response to reflect the new information

Comment: hey i have already tried this code.. and this works if i provide a domain user.. but how will it work for a local user.. the reason is i cant figure out the LDAp path??

Comment: @user175084 I've only had a domain user for when I've done it. Is there anyway to designate a domain account for lookups?